# Chrome Extension for loop inconsistent

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-chrome-extension

I'm running into an issue with a Chrome extension I'm currently working on. Its function is to take user input from the popup textarea and create tabs for each url separated by a line break. Overall, it successfully opens all urls 90% of the time but 10% of the time it only opens 7/10 urls in the textarea. Also, jquery 2.2.3 is used to get the values of the textarea, not sure if that matters.

I'm trying to figure out how/why it will occasionally only open 7/10 urls in the textarea and if it can be fixed. Below is the manifest, popup.html, and backend.js.

backend.js:

```
function urltoTabs(){
var text = $('textarea').val().split('\n');
  for (var h = 0; h <= text.length; h++) {
    if (text[h].length < 1) continue;
    chrome.tabs.create({url:text[h]});
  }
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('engage').addEventListener('click', urltoTabs);
});
```

popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="backend.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <p><strong>List urls below<strong><br />
            <textarea id="textarea" rows="15"></textarea></p>
            <button id="engage">Engage!</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Link to Tabs",
  "short_name": "Link To Tabs",
  "description": "Test url to tabs.",
  "version": "0.0.4",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "38",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["backend.js"]
    }],

  "permissions": [
          "tabs"
        ],

  "browser_action": {
          "default_icon": {                    
            "19": "assets/icon_16.png"           
          },
          "default_title": "New Tabs!",      
          "default_popup": "popup.html"        
        },

  "icons": {
    "16": "assets/icon_16.png",
    "128": "assets/icon_128.png"
  }
}
```

I appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Are you using the same urls each time?

Comment: No, they are unique to the user input.
For example:
https://www.google.com/1
https://www.google.com/2
https://www.google.com/3
https://www.google.com/4
https://www.google.com/5
https://www.google.com/6
https://www.google.com/7
https://www.google.com/8
https://www.google.com/9
https://www.google.com/10

Comment: okay, wasn't sure if you were just testing with a copy and paste list. hmm, the loop works fine, only thing i could think of is a hang up with chrome. maybe try putting a delay with setTimeout per tab creation. setTimeout(function(){ chrome.tabs.create({url:text[h]});}, h*200);

Comment: sorry, didn't mean to press enter. may need play around with the settimeout length. see if a lower number works, or try a larger one.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with popup behavior but... click on **Engage** button will start to create new tabs. Does this action also closes popup??? if so, this will also kill code inside it. Have you tried to send urls to background, and open tabs from there? (and probably close popup after msg is send....)

Comment: @flapjack17 I tried the setTimeout as you described but its throwing an error now stating "h" is undefined. Here's the exact error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

Comment: @WolfWar The popup closes once you navigate outside of it. So the action of clicking "engage" doesn't do it but when the new tabs are created and set as active this navigates the user away from the popup. That could be the issue, though I don't fully understand the "background" function in chrome extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer credit goes to @wolf-war

The issue was the popup would close once tabs were created which would close the operation prematurely. Pushing popup.html and backend.js to the background fixed this issue. All that changed was the manifest.json.

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Link to Tabs",
  "short_name": "Link To Tabs",
  "description": "Test url to tabs.",
  "version": "0.0.4",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "38",
  "background": {
    "js": "backend.js", // Needs both js and html to store user input correctly
    "page": "popup.html" 
  },
  "permissions": [
          "tabs"
        ],
        //content_scripts was removed
  "browser_action": {
          "default_icon": {                    
            "19": "assets/icon_16.png"           
          },
          "default_title": "New Tabs!",      
          "default_popup": "popup.html"        
        },

  "icons": {
    "16": "assets/icon_16.png",
    "128": "assets/icon_128.png"
  }
}
```

Thanks for all the help, I really appreciate it!